# php preg match. Find elements with two values not in order

Tags: php, preg-match

I got array like:

```
$array = array(
    3A32,
    4565,
    7890,
    0012,
    A324,
    9002,
    3200,
    345A,
    0436
);
```

Then I need to find which elements has two numbers. The value of number can change.

If values were:

```
$n1 = 0; 
$n2 = 3;
```

For that search `preg_match()` should return `(3200,0436)`

If values were:

```
$n1 = 0; 
$n2 = 0;
```

`preg_match()` should return `(0012,3200,9002)`

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `9002` when `$n1 = 0; $n2 = 3;`?

Comment: `0012` will become 12 itself. Isn't it

Comment: As well as kindly describe `$n1,$n2` concept here?

Comment: considere the array like $array = array('3A32','4565','7890','0012','A324','9002','3200','345A','0436');     Preg match should find the elements that contains both $n, then when $n1 = 0; $n2 = 3 are not in 9002 (3 is missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using preg_match, you might use [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and dynamically create a pattern that will match the 2 values in each order using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
^[A-Z0-9]*0[A-Z0-9]*3[A-Z0-9]*|[A-Z0-9]*3[A-Z0-9]*0[A-Z0-9]*$
```

The character class `[A-Z0-9]` matches either a char A-Z or a digit 0-9.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ofgonq/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/6gfo1)

If you want to use other characters, you could also take a look at [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to handle regular expression characters.

```
function getElementWithTwoValues($n1, $n2) {
    $pattern = "/^[A-Z0-9]*{$n1}[A-Z0-9]*{$n2}[A-Z0-9]*|[A-Z0-9]*{$n2}[A-Z0-9]*{$n1}[A-Z0-9]*$/";
    $array = array(
        "3A32",
        "4565",
        "7890",
        "0012",
        "A324",
        "9002",
        "3200",
        "345A",
        "0436"
    );

    return preg_grep($pattern, $array);
}

print_r(getElementWithTwoValues(0, 3));
print_r(getElementWithTwoValues(0, 0));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [6] => 3200
    [8] => 0436
)
Array
(
    [3] => 0012
    [5] => 9002
    [6] => 3200
)
```

Comment: This help me a lot!. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got your logic after looking multiple times on your input array as well as output based on given numbers.

***Since i am not good in regular expression at all,*** i will go to find out answer with commonly know PHP functions.

1.Create a function which takes initial array as well as those search numbers in array form (so that you can search any number and any length of numbers).

2.Now iterate over initial array, split each value to convert to array and do `array_count_value()` for both split array and numbers array. now apply check and see exact match found or not?

3.Assign this match to a new array declared under the function itself.

4.Return this array at the end of function.

```
$n1 = 0; 
$n2 = 0;

function checkValues($array,$numbers=array()){
    $finalArray = [];
    if(!empty($numbers)){
        foreach($array as $arr){
            $splitArr = str_split($arr);
            $matched = true;
            $count_number_Array = array_count_values($numbers);
            $count_split_array = array_count_values($splitArr);
            foreach($count_number_Array as $key=>$value){
                if(!isset($count_split_array[$key]) || $count_split_array[$key] < $value){
                    $matched = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($matched === true){
                $finalArray[] = $arr;
            }

        }

    }

    return $finalArray;
}

print_r(checkValues($array, array($n1,$n2)));
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/7uWfC And https://3v4l.org/Tuu5m And https://3v4l.org/fEKTO